# Changing Content Type Scope to Ghost Content Type and GUID

Tags: 2sxc

We have an instance where a portal that should have been using ghosted content types was not. Is it possible now that there is data records for these various content types to change to the ghosted content type and map to the master?

It does not seem right now there is option to change scope to Ghosted unless "other" is the option to select and then you have to know what to type in which maybe?

Perhaps this isn't possible. Is there a best method to handle this in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Ghost types are actually placeholder entries in the `ToSIC_EAV_AttributeSets` table. They usually have the same name as the original and have the original type ID in the column `UsesConfigurationOfAttributeSet`.

In addition to this, there are *no* entries in `ToSIC_EAV_AttributesInSets` for the ghost, as all attributes are inherited so the ghost doesn't have these entries. But a normal type has this, because the `ToSIC_EAV_Values` table uses the IDs to map a value to a specific attribute.

To "migrate" to such a setup is a bit messy but I guess you can do it. In the end you would need to have done all this:

1. Changed your `ToSIC_EAV_AttributeSets` to specify they are ghosts
2. Removed all entries in `ToSIC_EAV_AttributesInSets` for these types
3. fixed all `ToSIC_EAV_Values` to use the `AttributeId` of the correct field in the master

This is probably quite difficult. My guess is that it would be easier to do ca. this:

1. Export the list of one content-type
2. Make the changes on the `...AttributeSets` and `...AttributesInSets`
3. Restart DNN - it will then probably assume all the items exist, but are empty
4. Then re-import the data you exported before

This is just guess work, it's probably rarely done so there is no full guide on this.